# Kaa IOT Credential service

Tags: iot, kaa

How does the credential service work (Hope this is authentication in Kaa) ? How are the credentials passed from a simple kaa client program (in the context of custom credential service) ? How to use the custom credential service ?

Answer (score 0):

For details about Credentials management point to [Endpoint provisioning and registration](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Devices-provisioning-and-registration/). 
And try Credentials demos applications in [Sandbox](https://www.kaaproject.org/kaa-downloads). Visit GitHub pages for [Kaa Sandbox installation instructions](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Getting-started/).

Comment: I had gone over this documentation. To put it simple ,I have a simple Kaa client application ,I want to send some sensitive information as credentials to the custom credential service .....Is there an API to set this credential information ,which method in the "CredentialsService" interface gets called and how ? Is there any documentation explaining the lifecycle methods of any custom credential service ?

Comment: And when does those methods in credentialsservice interface called ? In the registration workflow "validate credentials" is depicted .....Can you please provide explanation on these framework methods ? and how it needs to be used ?